# Automatic build and publish projects in order

Tags: asp.net, build, visual-studio-2013

In Visual Studio I have a solution with 3 projects: DLL, web-service, asp.net pages.

To make everything work I do it in exact order:

1) Build DLL

2) Publish Services, that use this DLL (1) (build is automated before publishing)

3) Publish ASP.NET project, that uses the web-services from (2) (build is automated before publishing)

I'd like to know how in Visual Studio I can automate these steps of "build and publish" conform to described order.
Maybe there should be some VS macros or something?

Comment: You can using it by Team City

Comment: @Ramesh Rajendran, thanks